# Not able to update Nuget version Error "Cannot modify an evaluated object originating"

Tags: visual-studio-2019, nuget-package, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

When I am trying to install the latest version 10.0.3 of NewtonSoft.Json I get the error

```
Cannot modify an evaluated object originating in an imported file ""C:\code2\<my repo>\src\DassFHLSFApp1\packages\XX.XXXX.Core.1.0.126\build\XX.XXXX.Core.props"."
```

and it refers to another package's props file.

Any idea why am getting this error and how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

In my case the project had an old `.tt` file present in the file structure.

The `.csproj` had an exclusion for showing/compiling it, e.g.:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="BaseTemplate.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="BaseTemplate.tt" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="TemplateRunner.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>TemplateRunner.tt</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
```

nonetheless roslynator (in my case) would break when running against the project:

```
One or more errors occurred. (Cannot modify an evaluated object originating in an imported file "/home/me/.dotnet/sdk/6.0.404/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.props".)
  Inner exception: Cannot modify an evaluated object originating in an imported file "/home/me/.dotnet/sdk/6.0.404/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.props".
```

Adding `<EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>` to the `.csproj` fixed my issue.

I discovered this setting via https://github.com/Testura/Testura.Mutation/issues/11